# get most actual row with zend's fetchRow

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

I'm very new to zend (1.12)..so please excuse my very basic question:

I want to fetch only one row from a database. Thatfore I want to use the `fetchRow(..)` function like this

```
$row = $db->fetchRow($db->select()->where("col1 = '".val1."' AND col2='".val2."'"));
```

The problem is, that there may be many rows that fit to the where-clause and I only want to get the one with the highest id. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fetchRow() method returs only one row. If you want to choose row with the highest ID meeting other conditions, invoke it like this:

```
$select = $db->select()
             ->where('col1 = ?', $val1)
             ->where('col2 = ?', $val2)
             ->order('id DESC');
$row = $db->fetchRow($select);
```

Also, remember to pass values to SQL query in the way as in above code (to avoid SQL injection attack risk).